# Somando uma string em Ruby

Tags: ruby

tudo bem?
Estou aprendendo Ruby
então, estou com um exercício de Fundamentos em Ruby que pede o seguinte:
Tenho que somar os itens de uma string, o problema é que essa string está assim:

```
7
-3
10
0
-5
```

eu tentei usar reduce e até inject para que eles somassem, o problema é que eu não faço ideia de como colocar eles alinhados, tentei com chomp e não foi, ainda não tentei com gsub.

```
class Numbers
  def sum_text(numbers_text)
   numbers_text.map(&:to_f).reduce(:+)
  end
end
```

Comment: A partir do Ruby 2.4.6 você pode substituir esse `.reduce(&:+)` por `.sum`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creio que o truque é dar um `String.split` na string separando pelo caracter de quebra de linha `\n` (se for Windows e veio de um arquivo pode ser que venha `"\r\n"`). Deve retornar uma lista (em Ruby chama de array né?) com cada item sendo uma linha sem o `\n`, aí depois você processa esse array.

```
lines = numbers_text.split("\n")
```

Daí você faz: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538789/how-to-sum-array-of-numbers-in-ruby conforme a sua versão (possivelmente tenha que aplicar primeiro uma conversão de strings para inteiros).

Comment: MUITO OBRIGADA!!! Funcionou de primeiraa!!!

Comment: @IsabellaSantiago Por nada. Mas faça o [tour] para saber como agradecer melhor quando a pergunta lhe atendeu.